# Connection from a Class which inherits from QGraphicsItem to Objects on the ui

Tags: c++, qt, interface

Usually when I want to influence objects on the ui I'd use this from the mainwindow.cpp:

```
ui->nameOfObject.doStuff();
```

But now I want an object on the ui to change when a hover event for an object of my class "Ball" is triggered, but after several hours of digging in the documentation I haven't found an interface from a QGraphicsItem to the ui.
What would the best way be to get the data from my class to the ui?

So I tried doing what was suggested in the answers my code looks like this now:

```
mainwindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene (this);
    scene->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);

ui->graphicsView->setScene (scene);
}

void MainWindow::on_createNewBallButton_clicked()
{

    Ball *newBall = new Ball(newBallAngle, newBallRadius, newBallMass, newBallSpeed, newBallxCoordinate, newBallyCoordinate, ui);
    scene->addItem(newBall);
}
```

Ball.h

```
    public:
 Ball(double phi, double r, double m, double v, double x, double y, Ui::MainWindow *uivalue);


Ui::MainWindow *ui;
protected:
void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);
```

Ball.cpp

```
Ball::Ball(double phi, double r, double m, double v, double x, double y, Ui::MainWindow *uivalue )
{
    setAngle(phi);
    speed = v;
    mass = m;
    hasCollided = 0;
    radius = r;
    setPos(x, y);
    ui = uivalue;

}

void Ball::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent * event)
{
   double outSpeed = this->getV();
   double outAngle = this->getPhi();
   double outMass = this->getM();
   double outRadius = this->getR();
   double outxCoordinate = this->center().x();
   double outyCoordinate = this->center().y();
   ui->radiusOutput.setText(number(outRadius)); //Compiler: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::MainWindow'

}
```

But when I try and build this i get that error message from the compiler. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you should use signal/slot to communicate between UI and other classes. But here you deal with `QGraphicsItem` which is not a `QObject` subclass, so you can't use signal/slot. You can use `QGraphicsObject` of course, but it can reduce performance. So one way to solve the problem is to store the pointer to UI object and manipulate with it. Provide getter/setter for this object.

```
 void YourItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
 {
     if(pointer)
         pointer->setText("Ball!");
 }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand could you explain in a little more detail how would I store the pointer to the ui so I can call it in my class? The ui object I wanna manipulate is a QLineEdit if that info is of any relevance.

Comment: @Tomathor Very good! I really wanted to add explanation to my answer, but unfortunately I hadn't enough time to do it earlier.

Comment: sorry, but I still wasn't quite able to get it to work, I updated my post with the code I'm currently trying.

Comment: @Tomathor You passed whole ui pointer, but it breaks encapsulation very much. Pass only pointer to your lineEdit. But if you still want to operate with ui, then compiler tells that it can't found implementation of ui, so try to `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` in Ball.cpp